libvirt: Create a NAT-based virtual network that uses wireless connection

I have a libvirt host [QEMU/KVM] that has ethernet [eth0] and wireless [wlan0] interfaces:

etho: host uses it to access the local network
wlan0: I want VMs to exclusively use it to connect to the internet 

Since it's not possible to bridge a virtual network to wlan0, I've created a virtual network with NAT that forwards traffic to it, except it doesn't work:

VMs are unable to reach any network outside the host, but when eth0 is disabled, VMs can access the internet
From a guest, I can successfully ping both wlan0 address [192.168.0.190] and the default gateway of wlan0 [192.168.0.192)], but cannot go outside it (no internet connection) 



Virtual network:
<name>wifi</name>
<uuid>08fbd57e-a690-4003-a287-d632e42aed4a</uuid>
<forward dev="wlan0" mode="nat">
  <nat>
    <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
  </nat>
  <interface dev="wlan0"/>
</forward>
<bridge name="virbr1" stp="on" delay="0"/>
<mac address="52:54:00:21:cc:01"/>
<domain name="wifi"/>
<ip address="192.168.100.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
  <dhcp>
    <range start="192.168.100.128" end="192.168.100.254"/>
  </dhcp>
</ip>
</network>



Host:
$ ip a

  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 68:05:ca:e7:c0:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 10.10.10.7/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 fe80::5e7d:f1b0:b276:3c1a/64 scope link noprefixroute
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 6c:02:e0:5f:b1:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

  4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 50:3e:aa:b1:f5:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.0.190/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
        valid_lft 2223sec preferred_lft 2223sec
      inet6 fe80::87f7:d8bf:f6d9:72d4/64 scope link noprefixroute
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  11: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:91:42:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  30: virbr1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:21:cc:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



Guest:
$ ip a

  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

  2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 52:54:00:ca:7d:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.100.202/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
        valid_lft 3388sec preferred_lft 3388sec
      inet6 fe80::5054:ff:feca:7d4e/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever



iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5604:952083]
:INPUT ACCEPT [5094:911895]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2:72]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1751:398394]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1815:415293]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT

# Completed on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024

# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [5094:911895]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2:72]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1751:398394]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.100.0/24 -i wlan0 -o virbr1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.100.0/24 -i virbr1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr1 -o virbr1 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr1 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

# Completed on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024

# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [760:72548]
:INPUT ACCEPT [384:42924]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [104:9496]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [104:9496]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.100.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -o wlan0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o wlan0 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o wlan0 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.100.0/24 ! -d 192.168.100.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

# Completed on Wed Jul 31 09:45:57 2024




$ ip route

  default via 10.10.10.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
  default via 192.168.0.192 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.190 metric 600
  10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.7 metric 100
  192.168.100.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1
  192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
  192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.190 metric 600



